# Rendering points to a 3D texture without attaching each z-level as a layer

Tags: opengl

As the title says, is it possible to render points to a 3D texture without attaching each z-level as a layer and if so, how?

I want to render to a 64*64*64 texture, but individually attaching each z-layer seems unnecessarily verbose (and I bet it wouldn't give very good performance either).

Emulating a 3D texture using a 2D texture isn't possible either because I want to use the GL_TEXTURE_WRAP texture parameters for 3D.

Comment: Which version of OpenGL are you targeting? This is possible in OpenGL 3.2+ if you use `glFramebufferTexture (...)` to do this instead of individually attaching each image using `glFramebufferTextureLayer (...)` or the older `glFramebufferTexture3D (...)`.

Comment: I'm targeting modern core OpenGL, so glFramebufferbufferTexture definitely seems like the right way to do this. Thanks!